# How to get output in csv from a python script

Tags: python, django, csv

How to download output in csv file. i want to use this file with django application. which  will have a textbox and button. the input for this link function will be entered by user in that textbox. the given script is extracting href. please suggest.

**links.py**

```
import urllib2
import sys
def link(url):
    page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data=page.read().split("</a>")
    tag="<a href=\""
    endtag="\">"
    for item in data:
        if "<a href" in item:
            try:
                ind = item.index(tag)
                item=item[ind+len(tag):]
                end=item.index(endtag)
            except: pass
            else:
                print item
def main():
    link(sys.argv[1])

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What should the CSV data look like? The shown code just extracts links from HTML in the most crude and unrealiable way instead of using a HTML parser like BeautifulSoup or `lxml.html`. Where is the Django specific aspect here? Can you describe a little more what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: And if you just want to know how to create CSV files from Python, try googling this like @MarkoAdamko kindly did for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but if you need to transform something from python to csv file, you can look at CSV file reading and writing functions.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Hope it helps.